# Postgres - Combining SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a table with messages in a Postgres DB. 
When the user reads a message or a group of messages that belong together, I collect the message ids and, after the SELECT query, UPDATE the read flag to TRUE.

So it's just two simple queries, still memory-friendly. But I wonder if it could be improved anyhow, maybe by combining the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query? I use PHP/PDO for the database access.

Comment: What you want, then, is a single query to do the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`?

Comment: You can't mix Read and Write statements.

Comment: you can do this but there is no real gain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919056/implementing-an-update-on-select-in-postgres

Answer (score 1):

There is the [**`RETURNING`** clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) of the Postgres `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE msg_tbl
SET    read = TRUE
WHERE  msg_id = ?
RETURNING *;
```

But that is only an improvement if all rows actually *need* an `UPDATE`. If some already have `read = TRUE` that would cause empty updates ending up more expensive than a `SELECT` and a separate `UPDATE` with an additional `WHERE read = FALSE`.